# Update multiple rows based on an ordered array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table which has a position `pos` column to indicate the order that the items should be displayed in the UI:

```
|               list_has_task              |
|------------------------------------------|
| list_id (fk) | task_id (fk) | pos | meta |
| ------------ | ------------ | --- | ---- |
|         6969 |         1001 |  1  | abcd |
|         6969 |         1002 |  2  | efgh |
|         6969 |         1003 |  3  | ijkl |
|         6969 |         1004 |  4  | mnop |
|         6969 |         1005 |  5  | qrst |
                     (...)
```

When the user rearranges the list I get an ordered list of IDs as an array:

`(1004,1003,1002,1005,1001)`

I want to update those rows to that order.
Here is what I have:

```sql
BEGIN;
   UPDATE list_has_task SET pos = 1 WHERE list_id = 6969 AND task_id = 1004;
   UPDATE list_has_task SET pos = 2 WHERE list_id = 6969 AND task_id = 1003;
   UPDATE list_has_task SET pos = 3 WHERE list_id = 6969 AND task_id = 1002;
   UPDATE list_has_task SET pos = 4 WHERE list_id = 6969 AND task_id = 1005;
   UPDATE list_has_task SET pos = 5 WHERE list_id = 6969 AND task_id = 1001;
COMMIT;
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a multi-table `UPDATE` with a `VALUES` table:

```
UPDATE list_has_task AS l
SET pos = a.pos
FROM (VALUES (1, 1004), (2, 1003), (3, 1002), (4, 1005), (5, 1001)) AS a(pos, task_id)
WHERE l.task_id = a.task_id
```

Output:

```
list_id     task_id     pos     meta
6969        1004        1       mnop
6969        1003        2       ijkl
6969        1002        3       efgh
6969        1005        4       qrst
6969        1001        5       abcd
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b412/2)

Comment: This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Also I didn't know SQLFiddle existed! tysm

Comment: @Vitim.us yeah, SQLFiddle is good (I like its text to ddl feature), but there's also https://dbfiddle.uk which has a bigger range of DBMS available and https://db-fiddle.com which also has text to ddl

Comment: In MySQL, (VALUES ROW(1, 1004), ROW(2, 1003)) should work. Just need to add ROW keyword before each tuple.

Answer (score 2):

> I get an ordered list of IDs as an array.

You can use this ***directly***, `unnest()` and make use of the [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) feature:

```
UPDATE list_has_task l
SET    pos = x.ord
FROM   unnest('{1004,1003,1002,1005,1001}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY x(task_id, ord)
WHERE  l.list_id = 6969
AND    l.task_id = x.task_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2a510551488d3cb0f84a6474aad46e0)*

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, it's a bit different:

```sql
UPDATE
  real_table AS rt,
  (
    VALUES
      ROW(1, 1004),
      ROW(2, 1003),
      ROW(3, 1002),
      ROW(4, 1005),
      ROW(5, 1001)
  ) AS ft (pos, task_id)
SET
  rt.pos = ft.pos
WHERE
  rt.task_id = ft.task_id
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention MySQL, it's only tagged with PostgreSQL.